# Node Express app.get working on Mac but not Windows

Tags: node.js, express

```
app.get("/test", function(req, res, next) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/test.html');
});
```

Pretty basic, yes? Running this server on my Mac this works fine. Running this server on a PC my browser receives "cannot GET" error. I don't think the issue is the permissions on the mp4 file, they seem to be ok.

Comment: what mp4 file, you mention this and it's not in the code?

Comment: details missing. need more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys, not sure what I did differently but it is working now! 
For the record, here is the full app:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static('dist'));

app.get("/demo", function(req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'video/mp4');
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/demo.mp4');
});   

var server = app.listen(80, function () {});
```